# Recently upgraded from Firebase 8.8 => 8.16 and now I have Firebase Instance ID error

Tags: swift, firebase

I recently upgraded Firebase in my Swift app because I wanted to add App Check and I decided to update all the pods. Was only 8 minor releases 8.8 => 8.16. Now I am receiving

> Firebase Instance ID is not compatible with Firebase 8.x+. Please
> remove the dependency from the app.

I have removed my pods, cleaned, rebuilt, reinstalled.
I have restarted, cleaned, built.
I have removed App Check.
I have removed Messaging (which I've never used except for an experiment once).

I have no reference to Firebase Instance Id except in the `FIR` files which are Firebase's. Tried to follow the get started in the Firebase docs and they say use the Swift Package Manager (not sure if that was instead of CocoaPods?).

Any insight into this? It's obviously a new version issue, but would love to have to newest version for security vulnerability and any performance updates they've done. But my last resort will be to downgrade back to 8.8.

Comment: The most recent release is 8.12.1. InstanceID has not been compatible with any Firebase 8.x releases.

Comment: Did you find out how to fix this? I'm manually importing the framework and I'm not sure which one is causing the issue.

Comment: I had to remove cocoapods and use the Swift Package Manager - solved the issue.